# How to change commenting method in SCF by Volar?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, notepad++, vue-sfc

I use `Volar` extension in VS Code to edit SFC files for Vue. Also the `Notepad++ Keymap` extension is installed.

Everything works as expected, but I don't know how to change the commenting line command (ctrl+q) so it comments correctly in the `<style lang="scss">` section.

In the `<script>` section the command uses correctly the `//` characters, Idem in `<template>` where comments with `<!--` and `-->`. But in the `<style>` section it insists in using `<!--` and `-->` instead of `//`.

Is there anything to change or should I open an issue?

Thanks for helping!
mario

Comment: The Notepad++ keymap is a red herring. ctrl+q simply activate the `editor.action.commentLine` VSC command. Now, to open an issue, I need to understand if it is VSC or Volar problem.

Comment: Solved. Disabled extensions `Vue` and `Preview` apparently without side effects. Now commenting in the style session works as expected.

Comment: If you like, you can post this as a reply to your own question and pick it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Disabled extensions `Vue` and `Preview` apparently without side effects. Now commenting in the style section works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Add a file association** to tell vscode the vue file is something like a html
file by adding the fellowing code in 'settings.json' of vscode.

"files.associations": {
"*.vue": "html"
}